# How to escape Cypher meta-characters in a string node property

Tags: string, neo4j, properties, escaping, cypher

I have looked everywhere to find how to escape a question mark in a string literal node property. Example

```
CREATE (n:Utterance{title:"Simon_Says_002", Contents: "`Stop" + "," + "you have gone too far." + " `Don't you know that", Utterance_Number : 137}) RETURN n;
```

creates a node with all properties correct. the following do not

```
CREATE (n:Utterance{title:"Simon_Says_002", Contents: "`Stop" + "," + "you have gone too far." + " `Don't you know that" + "\?", Utterance_Number : 137}) RETURN n;

CREATE (n:Utterance{title:"Simon_Says_002", Contents: "`Stop" + "," + "you have gone too far." + " `Don't you know that\?", Utterance_Number : 137}) RETURN n;
```

I believe that Neo4j uses utf-16 encoding but I don't see that as relevant. Is there a list of metacharacters for Cypher and how to escape them in a string property? I have tried double backward/forward slashes \ and // nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Cypher only permits [using the backslash in limited ways](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#cypher-expressions-string-literals) within strings.

If you remove the backslash characters from your last 2 queries, they should work fine:

```
CREATE (n:Utterance{title:"Simon_Says_002", Contents: "`Stop" + "," + "you have gone too far." + " `Don't you know that" + "?", Utterance_Number : 137}) RETURN n;

CREATE (n:Utterance{title:"Simon_Says_002", Contents: "`Stop" + "," + "you have gone too far." + " `Don't you know that?", Utterance_Number : 137}) RETURN n;
```

If the programming language that you are using to generate the Cypher code uses question marks in a special way (and uses backslashes to escape that special behavior) you need to do whatever is appropriate in that language to prevent the backslashes from appearing in the generated Cypher code.

Comment: I used the quotes " around the comma because the neo4j manual said to do that. I am using windows 10 and am directly inputting the Cypher query to the neo4j server on my computer. There is no other language acting as intermediary.

Comment: I did not mention anything about commas in my answer, but can you provide a pointer to where the manual says that you need to quote commas? That seems very strange. Also, does my answer work for you?

Comment: I just located my problem. There is no need for escape characters. When I returned the node alone the properties did not show, I assumed an error. If I added return n.Contents then I was able to see that the property was there with the correct value. I would like to know how the neo4j server decides when to display property values vs when all it shows is the node without any property. Now that I am aware of this quirk, I know now to check if property values were assigned correctly but do I need to run something like MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)=47 RETURN n.property1 for each property?

Comment: basically, the recipe is to replace all " (double quotes) with ` (back quote) and put double quotes at the beginning and end of the string literal property value. It had no problems with ? ! or comma inside the double quote surrounded string property value. Funny such a simple solution was so hard to find on the internet.....

Comment: When Cypher returns a node, it returns all the properties of that node. But it is up to the client that receives the return value to decide what to do with the properties. For example: if you are using the neo4j [browser](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/) interface to interact with Cypher, then the browser's default Graph visualization will not show all the properties of every resulting node, since that will in general be way too much data to fit in the window. But you can use its "Table" or "Text" modes to see all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

basically, the recipe is to replace all " (double quotes) with ` (back quote) and put double quotes at the beginning and end of the string literal property value. It had no problems with ? ! or comma inside the double quote surrounded string property value. Funny such a simple solution was so hard to find on the internet.....

Comment: the corrected example above is   CREATE (n:Utterance{title:"Simon_Says_002", Contents: "`Stop, you have gone too far. Don't you know that?`", Utterance_Number : 137}) RETURN n.Contents;